# Finding pdes of velocity component and pressure

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

An incompressible viscous ﬂuid of constant density $ρ$
and kinematic viscosity $ν$ occupies the space above a solid boundary at $y = 0$ in two-dimensional Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$. For time $t < 0$, the liquid and solid wall are stationary. At time $t = 0$, the solid wall is suddenly jerked into motion with constant velocity $(U,0,0)$. For time $t > 0$,
the wall continues to move with the same speed. In the absence of gravity, the continuity and Navier-Stokes equations are $$∇·\textbf u = 0$$ $$ \frac{∂ \textbf u}{ ∂ t}
+(\textbf u·∇)\textbf u = −
\frac{1}ρ ∇p+
ν ∇^2 \textbf u$$
where $p$ is the pressure.

Assume $\textbf u = (u(y,t),0,0)$ and $p = p(y,t)$. Determine partial differential equations for $u(y,t)$ and $p(y,t)$.

---

Can someone guide me on how to do this please. Do we just rearrange the navier equation to find pressure. And for $u(y,t)$, isn't this just some function of $y$ and $z$? Because if the continuity equation holds, and the second and third of the velocity components are zero, then their partial derivatives would also be zero so you are just left with $\partial u / \partial x=0$ which gives $u=f(y,z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivation of the basic PDE requires a combination of mathematical and physical reasoning to eliminate variables, yet still render an acceptable solution to the Navier-Stokes equations.

Without an external body force component and a surface force component at the plate in the $z-$direction, there will be no velocity component in that direction, $w = 0,$ and no gradient $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0.$ Similarly, without mass injection or suction there will be no velocity component in the $y-$direction, $v = 0$. At high-speeds, instabilities could grow, inducing turbulence and non-zero velocity components / gradients in those directions, but the intent here is most likely to solve Stokes' first problem for the basic laminar flow.

The equation of continuity for incompressible flow, expressing conservation of mass, is

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}= 0.$$

With $v = w = 0$ we have

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0,$$

and since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0$ as argued above, it follows that  $ u = u(y,t)$.

The Navier-Stokes equations reduce to

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t } = -\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x } + \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2 }, \\ \frac{\partial p}{\partial y } = 0,\\ \frac{\partial p}{\partial z } = 0.$$

Hence, $p$ cannot depend on $y$ or $z$, and since $u$ depends only on $y$ and $t$ the $u-$momentum equation implies $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = C(t).$
If the pressure is uniform far from the plate, then in the absence of body forces (with gravity neglected) we can assume $C(t) = 0.$

The governing equation is

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t } = \nu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2 }, $$

and the boundary / initial conditions are

$$u(y,t) \to 0 \,\,\, \text{as} \,\,\, y \to \infty,\\ u(0,t) = U \,\,\, \text{for} \,\,\, t \geqslant 0+, \\u(y,0) = 0.$$

Comment: But how is $\partial p / \partial y =0$? $p$ is a function of $y$ and $t$ so how can you be sure it would be zero when diffed wrt y?

Comment: When you wrote the expression after you said "The Navier-Stokes..." should be $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= -\frac1{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial y} + v\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$$ shouldn't it? Because $p=p(y,t)$, not $p=p(x,t)$ which would give the equation you wrote...

Comment: @snowman: First, there is no $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}$ in the $u-$momentum equation because  $u$ is the velocity component in the $x-$direction.  The $x-$ direction component of $\nabla p$ should appear here and it is $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$.

Comment: Second, if we assume there is no velocity normal to the plate, $v = 0$ then the $v-$ momentum equation gives us $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} = 0$. Hence $p(y,t)$ is not the correct ansatz.  Only $u$ depends on $y$ because the fluid has to come to rest far from the surface of the plate.

Comment: OK I understand how you got your reduced N-S equation now. What do you mean by ansatz? I understand how $\partial p / \partial y =0$, since there is no velocity component for the $y$ direction (since $v=0$). But how is $\partial p / \partial x $ not equal to zero? We were asked to assume $p$ is dependent on $y$ and $t$ and then you deduced that it doesn't depend on $y$ so it must depend on $t$ only. But if this is the case then it does not depend on $x$ so $\partial p / \partial x =0$..........?

Comment: Ansatz is a term used often in solving differential equations. It means a guess for the form of the solution, later verified by finding a valid solution.

Comment: There is no reason to expect a pressure gradient in the x-direction.  Set it to $0$ and you find this solution. If not, then how will it be determined ?as there is only one differential equation for the function $u$.  Also you have to consider physics. A pressure gradient arises when there are external forces which are absent here.

Comment: Reading your comment again -- yes $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ can and should be assumed to be $0$

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The question asked for the pde of pressure but what exactly would this be?

Comment: Also if we were to find the boundary condition $u(y=0,t)$, would this be $U$ if $t \ge 0 $ and $0$ if $t<0$? And the condition of $u(y,t=0)$ is obviously just $U$ correct?

Comment: We know that at most $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} = C(t)$ if there is a time-dependent externally imposed pressure gradient.  But there is none so I would say $\nabla p = 0$ is the pde that applies in this problem.

Comment: This is a parabolic equation PDE.  The initial condition can be $u(y,0) = 0$ for $y>0$ and $u(0,0) = U.$  The discontinuity will diffuse away immediately. You say $u(y,t=0)  = U$. That is not correct -- only for $y=0$.

Comment: I am quite confused how y can be anything else but 0 because there v=0 for the velocity component of y. Please help.

Comment: Note that $x, y, z$ are the spatial coordinates. But $u, v, w$ are the velocity components in the $x-$, $y-$, and $z-$ directions, respectively.   The surface of the plate is at $y = 0$.  The velocity field at that surface is $u(0,t) = U, v = 0, w = 0$.  Away from the plate the velocity field is $u(u,t),v = 0, w=0$ .  I have answered the question to derive the pde for $u(y,t)$ function.